# CSS - How to change the location of checkbox input in a rtl direction page

Tags: html, css

In the link you can see that I'm using a CSS rule - "direction: rtl;".

All I'm trying to do is to move the plus(the one with the red border around it) to the left side of the tabs.

The labels are fine but it seems I having hard time to move checkbox to the other side.

I tried to change it's position also tried to float it to the left but it didn't worked.

Does someone have an idea how can I achieve that?

```css
    body{
        direction: rtl;
    }


/* Acordeon styles */
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}
/* :checked */
input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}
/* Icon */
label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .35s;
}
        
        
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "+";
   border: 1px solid #f00;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="half">
    <p>Open <strong>multiple</strong></p>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-one">Label One</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `right:0` to `left:0` for `label::after`

```css
body{
        direction: rtl;
    }


/* Acordeon styles */
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}
/* :checked */
input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}
/* Icon */
label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .35s;
}
        
        
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "+";
   border: 1px solid #f00;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="half">
    <p>Open <strong>multiple</strong></p>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-one">Label One</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `label::after { right:0}` to `label::after { left:0}`

its work

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="half">
    <p>Open <strong>multiple</strong></p>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-one">Label One</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```